# Graphics not working with Intel i5-3470

Tags: intel-graphics

I recently upgraded my PC to the following Spec:

- Processor: Intel Core i5-3470
- Motherboard: GA-B75M-D3H - GIGABYTE B75M-D3H IVY BRIDGE  MOTHERBOARD
- RAM: JM1333KLN-4G - TRANSCEND 4GB JETRAM DDR3 1333 DIMM 9-9-9
- HDD: ST31000524AS - SEAGATE 1TB 3.5"HDD 7200RPM SATA 6GB/S 32MB CACHE
- Graphics Card: Using the onboard graphics

When installing Ubuntu 12.04, all the boxes shown on screen as well as the menu bar across the top are corrupted. It seems to be a 3d related issue because 2d items such as pictures display in the install window and/or icons are ok during the install.

I can upload pictures later but basically all the boxes look as if they have horizontal and vertical tears/pixelation. The edges which are supposed to have a nice shadow effect are also all choppy and jagged. Text on the boxes is barely visible and as the text updates different letters become partially visible.

It was a bit difficult but I managed to setup my Wi-Fi (for updates) and complete the install.

When booting the background image displays as does the mouse cursor but then the screen just flickers a few times before turning off completely.

Pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1 gets me to the terminal prompt and I was able to run:
    $sudo apt-get update
    $sudo apt-get upgrade

After installing 305 updates the issue was still not resolved.

Does anybody have any ideas??
I also tried the 12.10 daily build but the Kernel crashed during install

I'm new to Ubuntu but so far this is really disappointing, I was hoping to use this PC for some development projects I had in mind but it doesn't work out the box! I also don'thave unlimited bandwidth so I can't keep downloading updates all the time.

Windows 7 worked just fine....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally a patch to fix this issue has been committed and the updated package (xserver) is now downloadable through package manager! I myself also confirmed this and it just works without the workaround of "nomodeset".

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1031784). A patch has been submitted though it has not yet made it in to the official repo. You can get the updated files using the [developer's PPA](http://ppa.launchpad.net/tjaalton) and following the instructions below:

1. Do a fresh install of 12.04, boot installer with nomodeset
2. On first boot add nomodeset in GRUB (hold shift on boot, press 'e' to edit)
3. Open a Terminal and type `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tjaalton/ppa`
4. Run `apt-get dist-upgrade`
5. Reboot

Note: I've found that upgrading the kernel to 3.6-rc1 breaks the Intel driver, it also seems to be incompatible with the xorg-edgers packages.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have exactly the same problems with mine including the processor (i5 3470) and the mother board as well. The solution that I found yesterday is to disable kernel mode setting feature by adding an kernel command line option [`nomodeset`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132). You can temporarily edit the command line in grub boot menu and if it works, you're going to make it permanent by editing grub configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the info - this fixed the issue with the installer but then I ran into the same issues when the system booted. Will try the `nomodeset` as part of Grub again now then...

Comment: The `nomodeset` worked well, thanks a lot! I just need to sort out the GPU hangs now but I think the other answers are pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score -1):

if you can login :
Firstly, Open terminal and type:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`
2. Followed by `sudo apt-get update`
3. And `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`

This will install INTEL latest drivers. Just reboot once installed and look for changes that have taken place.

If this does not work then try this testing PPA repository:

Open terminal type in:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:intel-gfx-testing/ppa`
2. Followed by `sudo apt-get update`

Once you are done, reboot and try to change resolution you are looking for.

Comment: Tired this and unfortunately it never worked, I also tried the XOrg Edgers repo's also with no luck. I do notice though that the i915 GPU hangs quite often, with the edgers updates its less frequent but still happens a lot

Comment: If you want to install software from `ppa:intel-gfx-testing/ppa` (or any PPA), it's not enough just to enable the PPA and run `sudo apt-get update`. You must actually upgrade to the versions provided, which you can usually do in the Update Manager or by running `sudo apt-get upgrade` or (if that's insufficient) `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. However, this particular PPA [has no software for any version of Ubuntu past 9.10](https://launchpad.net/~intel-gfx-testing/+archive/ppa). [xorg-edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) can be used instead for some packages.

Comment: Adding a file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf with this content: Section "Device"
   Identifier "Intel Graphics"
   Driver "intel"
   Option "SwapbuffersWait" "False"
   Option "RelaxedFencing" "False"
EndSection seemed to fix intel graphics stability problems for me. I have Levono T500 with Intel GM45 Express (i965) graphics.

Comment: @EliahKagan - I did run the upgrade immediately after adding the PPA. Unfortunately it seems like there are no updates available from intel-fx-testing since I am also using the xorg-edgers.

Comment: @FlareCoder - That sounds like some good info, I'll try it out as soon as I get a chance, stuck at work now unfortunately

Comment: @EliahKagan @FlareCoder is using a 4 year old laptop, his solution is probably not related to newer models since those use a different GPU. Also if you're telling someone in an answer to install a PPA and it doesn't work out as expected, tell them how to remove the PPA the correct way (`ppa-purge`). That would be nice.

Comment: I had to add this option too: Option "TripleBuffer" "False" . Now the graphics has been quite stable. So this is the content of my 20-intel.conf file: Section "Device"
   Identifier "Intel Graphics"
   Driver "intel"
   Option "SwapbuffersWait" "False"
   Option "RelaxedFencing" "False"
   Option "TripleBuffer" "False"
EndSection

Comment: @EliahKagan the part on ppa-purge wasn't meant to be directed to you, sorry for that.