# Graphical artifacts during installation with Intel based graphics

Tags: 12.04, installation, intel-graphics, visual-artifacts

I downloaded and burned the 12.04 (64bit) desktop ubuntu image to a CD and booted to it.  It gave me a visible desktop, but the interface is badly broken, with ghosting when dialog boxes are moved and blocky artifacts covering all text.

I tried using the self verification tool (boot, hold down a button for menu, select "Verify CD"), which claims that the CD is fine.  What can I try next?

I'm using the Intel HD 4000 integrated graphics.

Update:  I just kept clicking "next" and hoping that the defaults would be acceptable.  Ubuntu finished installing, and I rebooted into the fresh install.  The graphics artifacts appear to still be there, but I can't quite tell because all of the UI elements except for the desktop background disappear a few seconds after logging in, and I don't know how to interact with the system.  (Is there a hotkey to bring up a console?)

Update 2: I did all of the above with 12.04 32-bit, with the same results.  Are there any known issues with ubuntu and Intel integrated graphics?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware failure to me. Have you tried other operating systems on that machine?

Comment: @stonedsquirrel Windows 7 appears to be working fine.  The wubi-installed version of ubuntu I had on the drive before the blind overwriting installation was working fine.

Comment: This may be ivy-bridge related. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/172173/ivy-bridge-graphics-not-working-core-i5-hd-2500 for possible solutions. Let us know if the answer there works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user68186's comment gave me the answer.

Using the method described on the [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132), I set `nomodeset` so that the software does not attempt to use fancy graphics until the X window system has started, and the artifacts disappeared from both installer and installed OS.

In case of link rot:

- When installing from the CD, press F6 and select `nomodeset` before selecting install.
- Upon first boot, select your Ubuntu install in grub and press `e` to edit it.  Add `nomodeset` to the end of the line that begins with `/boot`.
- Once you're in Ubuntu, open the terminal and run the command `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub` Edit the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to read `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`.

The UI outside of the X windows system doesn't look nearly as pretty but it's a small price to pay for a usable system on my shiny new box.